# The correct pattern for Cases

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a problem that, admittedly, I have already solved using `Select` instead, but it is irking me that I cannot seem to construct the right pattern to solve it using `Cases`.  I would like the output of

```
Cases[
    {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}, {{}, {}}},
    (* THE CORRECT PATTERN HERE *)
]
```

to be

```
{{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}}
```

In other words, I would like a pattern that picks up all the elements of the outer list that have at least one non-empty list as an element.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you want to do like this. Cases[
 {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}, {{}, {}}}, Except[{{}, {}}]]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}, {{}, {}}};
Cases[list, Except[{{} ..}]]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}} *)
```

or

```
Cases[list, {___, Except[{}], ___}]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}} *)
```

You can also use `PatternTest` (`_?func`) where `func` is any selector function that you might have used as the second argument of `Select`. For example:

```
Select[list, Union @@ # =!= {} &]  (* or Flatten @ # =!= {} & or  ... *)
(* {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}}  *)

Cases[list, _?(Union @@ # =!= {} &)]
(*  {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}} *)
```

Comment: Oh, wow!  I didn't realize the solution would be that simple.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Shredderroy, my pleasure.

Comment: @kguler so good ...

Comment: `Cases[list, {___, {__}, ___}]` seems simpler and faster.

Comment: @MichaelE2, that is surprising!  Makes you think; I wouldn't have expected it to work; now i think i see why it works ... -- which makes pattern puzzles such fun  :) I would be happy to add to my answer but I think you should post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @kguler Thanks.  I took you up on your invitation.  I was afraid that it was a little too like your answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2, just saw/upvoted your post. I think it is much more elegant/unexpected not to mention faster:)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a way, that is a bit like [@kguler's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kguler), but it's simpler and a little faster:

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}, {{}, {}}};

Cases[list, {___, {__}, ___}]
(*
  {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}}
*)
```

The pattern `___` (three underscores or [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankNullSequence.html)) matches zero or more things and the pattern `__` (two underscores or [`BlankSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html)) matches one or more things.  So the pattern `{___, {__}, ___}` represents a list containing

1. zero or more things, followed by
2. a list containing at least one thing, followed by
3. zero or more of things.

All in all, it matches a list that contains at least one element that is a nonempty list. `Cases` will match this against the elements of `list` at level one.

Comment: nice. May be you explain a little for us newbies how this works :)

Comment: Michael, this made me realize that i could also use the pattern `{___, Except[{}], ___}` instead of the earlier contraption `{___,{___,Except[{}],___},___}`...

Answer (score 7):

Unless you have other requirements I recommend `DeleteCases`:

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}, {{}, {}}};

DeleteCases[list, {{} ..}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}}
> ```

For deletion at all levels you could use:

```
list /. {{} ..} -> Sequence[]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}}
> ```

Comment: I don't think it will work for all levels. check this: {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 
    5, {5}}}, {{6}, {}, {}}, {{}, {{}, {}}}, {{}, {}, {2}}};

Comment: @Algohi It does work on that list but it doesn't remove the new expression `{{}}` that is created.  That is a different interpretation from what I intended.  If you with to remove that you could use `//.` but be aware that it is inefficient.  For greater efficiency one might use: `Replace[list, {({} | _Sequence) ..} -> Sequence[], {1, -1}]`

Answer (score 3):

> that picks up all the elements of the outer list that have at least
>   one non-empty list as an element.

I think Except is the logical choice and more functional also. But for fun, since `Length[]` applied to {{}} gives zero (after Flatten), may be this can be used to check

```
lis = {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}, {{}, {}}};
Cases[lis, x_ /; Length[Flatten@x] > 0]
     (*  {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}} *)
```

Or can do direct compare to {} (after Flatten also)

```
lis = {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}, {{}, {}}};
Cases[lis, x_ /; Not[SameQ[Flatten@x, {}]]]
   (* {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}} *)
```

another test

```
lis = {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}, {{}, {}}, {{}, {}, {2}}};
Cases[lis, x_ /; Not[SameQ[Flatten@x, {}]]]
   (* {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {}}, {{}, {}, {2}}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

How a bout this for all levels:

```
lis = {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 
     5, {5}}}, {{6}, {}, {}}, {{}, {{}, {}}}, {{}, {}, {2}}};
    Select[lis , #/# =!= # || # =!= # + # &] // Quiet
      (* {{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5, {5}}}, {{6}, {}, {}}, {{}, {}, {2}}} *)
```