# Expansion on sums of NonCommutativeMultiply

Tags: symbolic, algebra

Following the MMa's documentations, the `ExpandNCM[]` function expands `a**(b+c)` without efforts (although I don't have very good idea how it works). However it got stuck if I tried use it to expand summations of two expressions for example: `a1**(b1+c1)+a2**(b2+c2),` the output is itself with no expansions. The function is defined below. Please help! Thanks a lot.

```
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := 
 Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM[h[##]] &]

ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Times, c___]] := 
 Most[b] ExpandNCM[h[a, Last[b], c]]

ExpandNCM[a_] := ExpandAll[a]
```

Comment: The standard recommendation seems to be to use the `NCAlgebra` package for non-commutative algebra.  I haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for expansions at any level of the expression:

```
ClearAll[ExpandNCM];

ExpandNCM[expr_] := expr /.
    {(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___] :> 
            Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM@*h],
     (h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Times, c___] :> 
            Most[b] ExpandNCM[h[a, Last[b], c]]
    };
```

Examples:

```
a1 ** (b1 + c1) // ExpandNCM
(* a1 ** b1 + a1 ** c1 *)

a1 ** (b1 c1) // ExpandNCM
(* b1 a1 ** c1 *)

a1 ** (b1 + c1) + a2 ** (b2 + c2) // ExpandNCM
(* a1 ** b1 + a1 ** c1 + a2 ** b2 + a2 ** c2 *)

a1 ** (b1 c1) + a2 ** (b2 c2) // ExpandNCM
(* b1 a1 ** c1 + b2 a2 ** c2 *)

a1 ** (b1 + c1) + a2 ** (b2 + c2 ** (b3 + c3)) // ExpandNCM
(* a1 ** b1 + a1 ** c1 + a2 ** b2 + a2 ** c2 ** b3 + a2 ** c2 ** c3 *)

a1 ** (b1 c1) + a2 ** (b2 c2 ** (b3 c3)) // ExpandNCM
(* b1 a1 ** c1 + b2 b3 a2 ** c2 ** c3 *)

{1, a1 ** (b1 + c1), {a1 ** (b1 c1)}} // ExpandNCM
(* {1, a1 ** b1 + a1 ** c1, {b1 a1 ** c1}} *)
```

Comment: @hggreen Great, I'm glad this was helpful.

Comment: are there any references for symbols like "_ _ _" and "a_ _ _ " inside the function definition? I would love to learn more for the logic behind the function – hggreen 2 mins ago    edit

Comment: @hggreen `__` is called a `BlankSequence`, and `a__` is a named `BlankSequence` (with name `a`). You can find some references in the documentation, [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html). There are also nice posts in this forum about the use of these symbols, for instance [(6588)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/can-a-function-be-made-to-accept-a-variable-amount-of-inputs) and [(58325)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58325/the-correct-pattern-for-cases).