# Defining function recursively with increasing variables

Tags: function-construction, code-request

I am exploring my question [l,r-operations on words $[[[1,2],3],4] \cdots, n]$, $[1,[2,[3,\cdots, [n-1,n]\cdots ]]]$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241915/l-r-operations-on-words-1-2-3-4-cdots-n-1-2-3-cdots-n-1-n-cd), through some sample implementation.

As a trial, I built

```
ClearAll[l1, l2, l3, l4,l5]
l1[x_] := x;
l2[x_, y_] := x ** y - y ** x;
l3[x_, y_, z_] := l2[l2[x, y], z];
l4[x_,y_,z_,k_]:= l2[l3[x,y,z],k];
l5[x_,y_,z_,k_,l_] := l2[l4[x,y,z,k],l];
```

Sadly I realized, my `l3[x,y,z] =-z ** (x ** y - y ** x) + (x ** y - y ** x) ** z` and the mathematica does not do any distributive law, for example I want to make this as `x**y**z - z**x**y - y**x**z + z**y**x` without parentheses.

Anyway, I want to construct such iterative function for fixed $n$. i.e., If I determined the number $n$(for example $n=100$) I want mathematica to produce `l100` immediately. Is there any way to implement in this way?

Comment: `ExpandNCM[expr_] := expr /.
   {(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___] :> 
     Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, 
      ExpandNCM@*h], (h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Times, 
      c___] :> Most[b] ExpandNCM[h[a, Last[b], c]]};
Fold[#1 ** #2 - #2 ** #1 &, {x, y, z}] // ExpandNCM`

Comment: `Fold[#1 ** #2 - #2 ** #1 &, Array[A, 10]] // ExpandNCM`

Comment: @cvgmt, I think now I understand your code. So 

>> Fold[#1 **#2 - #2 **#1 &, Array[A,10]]//ExpandNCM

gives $l$ operation on $\{A[1],\cdots, A[10]\}$.  I realized ExpandNCM is nothing but a distributive law for non-commutative variables, and the key construction of your code is the command "Fold". I tried to built $r$-operation from Fold, but couldn't do it. 

How about $r$ operations?

Comment: You get the r operations by Reversing the original list.

Comment: @DanielHuber, Yes by reversing the list and proper (-1) I got the $r$-operation from $l$-functions!